# Google Drive Realtime API callbacks in .NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

Trying to implement a collaborative model using the google drive realtime API for .NET on an existing C# / VB.NET project. Google's .NET Drive sample is working just fine, but I can't find any way to receive a callback or event notifying me of another user's changes. There isn't any documentation specific to the .NET wrapper, and I'm not even certain that the .NET wrapper includes the whole Realtime API; RealtimeResource is rather opaque. Any hints would be very gratefully received.

If and when I get this going, I'll post around a working example, the realtime API seems too useful to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The realtime api is currently only available in JavaScript.